# change sunpy / pyplot color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've tried for several hours to change the default white background black labels/axes when plotting with sunpy to a black background & white labels/axes.

Basically I want to...

```
ax = sunpy_map.plot()
sunpy_map.draw_limb()
# somehow change label/text/limb etc. to white
plt.savefig(get_image_name(bin, flare_id), bbox_inches='tight', facecolor='black', edgecolor='black')
```

I've tried many things but haven't found a solution yet. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean the *entire* background black (Rather than just inside the axes)?

Comment: Yes, alike this image: http://hsp.cs.technik.fhnw.ch/flaredata/15011115/3848/coarse/3_1136957982.8165888786315918_131_visclean_photon.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SunPy uses Matplotlib to do its plotting tasks you can maybe accomplish what you want by modifying [matplotlibrc](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) (note that I can't test this with SunPy):

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rc('savefig', facecolor='black')
matplotlib.rc('axes', edgecolor='white')
matplotlib.rc('xtick', color='white')
matplotlib.rc('ytick', color='white')
matplotlib.rc('axes', labelcolor='white')
matplotlib.rc('axes', facecolor='black')

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

[image]

Comment: This changes http://s11.postimg.org/4r8wnfwoz/plotwhite.png to http://s11.postimg.org/6hrxoxe83/plotblack.png. I.e. the colorbar's labels are white, nothing else tho and I'm also not sure whether your solution covers the drawn limb. But thanks a ton already!

Comment: @Doidel Maybe you are overriding these new defaults elsewhere in your code? (You have `edgecolor = 'Black'` above, for example). And no, it doesn't include the drawn limb, as you only mentioned the background and axes / labels. You need the plot itself in while as well?

Comment: It works! Thanks a ton ^^
I don't know what made it work in the end, I now use 'fig = plt.figure(); ax = plt.subplot(); sunpy_map.plot()' and then plot it. But your approach worked for me in the end, many thanks!